# How to color code timevis plot in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to color code timevis output plot according to the Date_Bucket column, any help would be highly appreciated.

```html
head(file)
Record_ID Start End Date_Bucket
1 01-01-2017 31-12-2021 Greater than 2 Years
2 01-11-2013 31-10-2028 Greater than 2 Years
3 01-11-2017 31-10-2022 Greater than 2 Years
4 22-04-2014 30-09-2020 1-2 Years
5 15-12-2017 30-06-2019 0-6 Months
6 01-11-2017 31-10-2022 Greater than 2 Years
7 22-04-2014 30-09-2020 1-2 Years
8 11-01-2013 31-08-2019 6-12 Months
9 11-10-2013 31-08-2019 6-12 Months
```

```
file$Start <- as.Date(file$Start)
file$End <- as.Date(file$End)

if (interactive()) 
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
  timevisOutput("timeline"),
  actionButton("btn", "Fit all items")
),
server = function(input, output) {
  output$timeline <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(data.frame(
     id = file$Record_ID, start =  file$Start , end = file$End, content = 
 file$Date_Bucket
    ))
  )
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    fitWindow("timeline", list(animation = TRUE))
  })
 }
 )
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple naive way to achieve what you want. Based on your usecase and number of distinct values (and whether it's a static or dynamic number), you may want to do something a bit more clever, but this should be a good start. You may also want to add more CSS so that the outline of each box isn't blue. Essentially all I'm doing here is using the `className` parameter of timevis to assign a different class to each Date_Bucket, and adding CSS for each of these classes.

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

file$Start <- as.Date(file$Start)
file$End <- as.Date(file$End)
cols <- c("redBg", "blueBg", "greenBg", "orangeBg")
file$className <- cols[file$Date_Bucket]

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$style(
      ".redBg { background: red; }
      .blueBg { background: blue; }
      .greenBg { background: green; }
      .orangeBg { background: orange; }"
    ),
    timevisOutput("timeline"),
    actionButton("btn", "Fit all items")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$timeline <- renderTimevis(
      timevis(data.frame(
        id = file$Record_ID, start =  file$Start , end = file$End, content = 
          file$Date_Bucket, className = file$className
      ))
    )
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      fitWindow("timeline", list(animation = TRUE))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi Dean, Unfortunately your above solution does not work for me. I used your exact code, maintaining the new column name as `className` in the data.frame passed in the `data=` argument to `timevis()` function. I also inserted the `tagStyle(),`  as above, just before the `timevisOutput()`; 

Still the boxes donot change their background color. 

This is a highly desired functionality so if you could build it out of the box in the package it would be fantastic ! Many thanks in advance for reading the comment. Keep doing the fantastic work you do. Cheers!